# Error compiling FFMPEG / libav code after adding avfilter

Tags: c, docker, video, ffmpeg, libav

My encoding and decoding was working fine using ffmpeg and libav, but then I added a filter in the encoding step to rotate my video and it no longer works in my docker machine, BUT it does work locally.

The error message when compiling in docker is

```
//usr/local/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_pp.o): In function `pp_init':
/var/tmp/ffmpeg/libavfilter/vf_pp.c:56: undefined reference to `pp_get_mode_by_name_and_quality'
//usr/local/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_pp.o): In function `pp_uninit':
/var/tmp/ffmpeg/libavfilter/vf_pp.c:161: undefined reference to `pp_free_mode'
/var/tmp/ffmpeg/libavfilter/vf_pp.c:163: undefined reference to `pp_free_context'
//usr/local/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_pp.o): In function `pp_filter_frame':
/var/tmp/ffmpeg/libavfilter/vf_pp.c:142: undefined reference to `pp_postprocess'
//usr/local/lib/libavfilter.a(vf_pp.o): In function `pp_config_props':
/var/tmp/ffmpeg/libavfilter/vf_pp.c:115: undefined reference to `pp_get_context'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

These are my relevant configurations in docker file

```
# Install libx264 for video encoding.
RUN cd /var/tmp && curl -L http://ftp.videolan.org/pub/videolan/x264/snapshots/x264-snapshot-20190103-2245-stable.tar.bz2 > x264.tar.bz2 && \
    echo "21cb6e2bb660f863713fb9f752654c65191e032dac1329ec113786c69f0f75c1  x264.tar.bz2" > x264.sha256sum && \
    shasum -a 256 -c x264.sha256sum && \
    tar xjf x264.tar.bz2 && \
    cd x264-snapshot-20190103-2245-stable && \
    ./configure \
        --enable-static \
        --enable-pic \
        --disable-cli \
        --disable-avs \
        --disable-opencl && \
    make -j8 && \
    make install-lib-static

# Compile ffmpeg.
COPY ffmpeg.tar /var/tmp/ffmpeg.tar
RUN cd /var/tmp && tar xf ffmpeg.tar && \
    cd ffmpeg && \
    ./configure \
        --cc=/usr/bin/clang-6.0 \
        --cxx=/usr/bin/clang++-6.0 \
        --extra-libs="-lpthread" \
        --enable-gpl \
        # without pic - opencv will throw up errors
        --enable-pic \
        --enable-libx264 \
        --disable-network && \
     make -j 8 && \
     make install
```

Not sure this is relevant but here are my flags

```
LDFLAGS: -lavcodec -lavfilter -lswscale -lavutil -lswresample -lx264 -lm -lz
```

Here's my local ffmpeg configuration and version

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
```

Here's the output from my docker machine

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with clang version 6.0.0-1~bpo9+1 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang-6.0 --cxx=/usr/bin/clang++-6.0 --extra-libs=-lpthread --enable-gpl --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --disable-network
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
```

How can I get my configuration fixed so it works like in local? I didn't specifically configure my local environment so it's going to be using default configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `-lpostproc` in your **LDFLAGS**. Also, the order should be correct:

```
LDFLAGS=-lavfilter -lswscale -lpostproc -lswresample -lavcodec -lavutil -lx264 -lm -lz
```

Comment: wow this worked thanks a lot. Mind giving a little more details on what was wrong? Why do I need this flag, how do i determine correct order?

Comment: I thought that you missed `-lpostproc` because **pp_free_mode** and the other undefined references all come from that library. If you don't know ffmpeg code by heart *(I don't)*, there's always **grep** at your disposal to look for the symbol in code or in libraries.

Comment: As for the order, it's only relevant when you use static ffmpeg libs. The problem is that the linker usually makes only one pass over the static libraries on the command line, from left to right. Therefore, `-lavcodec` and `-lavutil`, which provide foundation for many things done by other ffmpeg libraries, should be the the last ones.

Comment: Cool I'll definitely do that in the future. You seem to have a good handle on the library. I'm also struggling with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719959/rotating-a-video-during-encoding-with-ffmpeg-and-libav-api-results-in-half-of-vi