# Rotating a video during encoding with ffmpeg and libav API results in half of video corrupted

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, libav, libavcodec

I'm using the C API for ffmpeg/libav to rotate a vertically filmed iphone video during the encoding step. There are other questions asking to do a similar thing but they are all using the CLI tool to do so.

So far I was able to figure out how to use the `AVFilter` to rotate the video, base off this example https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/filtering_video.c

The problem is that half the output file is corrupt.
[image: Corrupt Video Screenshot]

Here is the code for my encoding logic. Its written with GOLANG using CGO to interface with the C API.

```
// Encode encode an AVFrame and return it
func Encode(enc Encoder, frame *C.AVFrame) (*EncodedFrame, error) {
    ctx := enc.Context()

    if ctx.buffersrcctx == nil {
        // initialize filter
        outputs := C.avfilter_inout_alloc()
        inputs  := C.avfilter_inout_alloc()
        m_pFilterGraph := C.avfilter_graph_alloc()
        buffersrc := C.avfilter_get_by_name(C.CString("buffer"))
        argsStr := fmt.Sprintf("video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d", ctx.avctx.width, ctx.avctx.height, ctx.avctx.pix_fmt, ctx.avctx.time_base.num, ctx.avctx.time_base.den, ctx.avctx.sample_aspect_ratio.num, ctx.avctx.sample_aspect_ratio.den)
        Log.Info.Println("yakotest")
        Log.Info.Println(argsStr)
        args := C.CString(argsStr)
        ret := C.avfilter_graph_create_filter(&ctx.buffersrcctx, buffersrc, C.CString("my_buffersrc"), args, nil, m_pFilterGraph)
        if ret < 0 {
            Log.Info.Printf("\n problem creating filter %v\n", AVError(ret).Error())
        }

        buffersink := C.avfilter_get_by_name(C.CString("buffersink"))
        ret = C.avfilter_graph_create_filter(&ctx.buffersinkctx, buffersink, C.CString("my_buffersink"), nil, nil, m_pFilterGraph)
        if ret < 0 {
            Log.Info.Printf("\n problem creating filter %v\n", AVError(ret).Error())
        }

        /*
         * Set the endpoints for the filter graph. The filter_graph will
         * be linked to the graph described by filters_descr.
         */

        /*
         * The buffer source output must be connected to the input pad of
         * the first filter described by filters_descr; since the first
         * filter input label is not specified, it is set to "in" by
         * default.
         */
        outputs.name       = C.av_strdup(C.CString("in"))
        outputs.filter_ctx = ctx.buffersrcctx
        outputs.pad_idx    = 0
        outputs.next       = nil

        /*
         * The buffer sink input must be connected to the output pad of
         * the last filter described by filters_descr; since the last
         * filter output label is not specified, it is set to "out" by
         * default.
         */
        inputs.name       = C.av_strdup(C.CString("out"))
        inputs.filter_ctx = ctx.buffersinkctx
        inputs.pad_idx    = 0
        inputs.next       = nil

        ret = C.avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(m_pFilterGraph, C.CString("transpose=clock,scale=-2:1080"),
            &inputs, &outputs, nil)
        if ret < 0 {
            Log.Info.Printf("\n problem with avfilter_graph_parse %v\n", AVError(ret).Error())
        }

        ret = C.avfilter_graph_config(m_pFilterGraph, nil)
        if ret < 0 {
            Log.Info.Printf("\n problem with graph config %v\n", AVError(ret).Error())
        }
    }

    filteredFrame :=  C.av_frame_alloc()

    /* push the decoded frame into the filtergraph */
    ret := C.av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(ctx.buffersrcctx, frame, C.AV_BUFFERSRC_FLAG_KEEP_REF)
    if ret < 0 {
        Log.Error.Printf("\nError while feeding the filter greaph, err = %v\n", AVError(ret).Error())
        return nil, errors.New(ErrorFFmpegCodecFailure)
    }

    /* pull filtered frames from the filtergraph */
    for {
        ret = C.av_buffersink_get_frame(ctx.buffersinkctx, filteredFrame)
        if ret == C.AVERROR_EAGAIN || ret == C.AVERROR_EOF {
            break
        }
        if ret < 0 {
            Log.Error.Printf("\nCouldnt find a frame, err = %v\n", AVError(ret).Error())
            return nil, errors.New(ErrorFFmpegCodecFailure)
        }

        filteredFrame.pts = frame.pts
        frame = filteredFrame
        defer C.av_frame_free(&filteredFrame)
    }

    if frame != nil {
        frame.pict_type = 0 // reset pict type for the encoder
        if C.avcodec_send_frame(ctx.avctx, frame) != 0 {
            Log.Error.Printf("%+v\n", StackErrorf("codec error, could not send frame"))
            return nil, errors.New(ErrorFFmpegCodecFailure)
        }
    }

    for {
        ret := C.avcodec_receive_packet(ctx.avctx, ctx.pkt)
        if ret == C.AVERROR_EAGAIN {
            break
        }
        if ret == C.AVERROR_EOF {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("EOF")
        }
        if ret < 0 {
            Log.Error.Printf("%+v\n", StackErrorf("codec error, receiving packet"))
            return nil, errors.New(ErrorFFmpegCodecFailure)
        }

        data := C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(ctx.pkt.data), ctx.pkt.size)
        return &EncodedFrame{data, int64(ctx.pkt.pts), int64(ctx.pkt.dts),
            (ctx.pkt.flags & C.AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY) != 0}, nil
    }

    return nil, nil
}
```

It seems like I need to do something with the scaling here but I'm struggling to find helpful information online.

Comment: How do you run ffmpeg on iPhone? Do you use [mobile-ffpeg](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg)?

Comment: This code is running on a server, im just passing a video filmed on an iphone. The video is filmed vertically so it includes metadata about the rotation but the video isn't actually rotated. It has horizontal dimensions it just includes rotation metadata. Video players use this to automatically rotate the video but I'm editing the video and need it to be actually rotated. I updated the description to make that more clear

Comment: Now I don't understand what went wrong. Each frame has the bad green rectangle on the bottom? Or this applies to some frames?

Comment: Ya the output video looks like this all the way through

Comment: … but the piece that is on the top, comes out the way you expect it, without distortion or cropping? In this case, maybe all your trouble is that you set the height of the frame wrong.

Comment: I'm not explicitly setting a frame height anywhere though, the only place where I set height options is on the `AVCodecContext` and there I set the height and width to the src media

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213647/discussion-between-alex-cohn-and-daniel-kobe).