# Get displaymatrix and change it using ffmpeg C API

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg

Due to how phones are oriented if a phone takes a picture with portrait mode, the video seems to have an aspect ratio where height is greater than width, but the buffer inside it is rotated.

Here is what I'm trying to mean, originally, when displayed through "Videos" on debian 11 the video looks like this:

[image: Source video]

But when I normally use it with ffmpeg (I write the data I got from decoder to an opengl texture and display it) and view it on firefox it looks like this (Ignore the background being green it's intentional):

[image: Ffmpeg displayed video]

As you can see even though the aspect ratios are the same (roughly 500x1000), for some reason ffmpeg and firefox displays the video like that.

I've deduced that there is a metadata called display matrix that show's me a rotation value. This rotation value is in fact there because the video is shot from an Iphone which does add a rotation data depending on how you are holding the phone while recording (in this case it's held vertically)

I can see the rotation metadata using this ffprobe command:

```
ffprobe phone_video.mp4
```

Along the lines of the output I can see this:

```
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
```

Which is exactly what I need. It is indeed rotated 90 degrees.  However I can't access this inside my C/C++ code, here is what I've tried so far:

```cpp
for (int j = 0; j < av_frame->nb_side_data; j++) 
{
    AVFrameSideData *sd = av_frame->side_data[j];

    if(sd->type == AV_FRAME_DATA_DISPLAYMATRIX) 
    {
        float a =  av_display_rotation_get((int32_t *)sd->data);
        PRINT_INFO("=> displaymatrix: rotation of {} degrees",a );
    }
}
```

This results in no output so far.

Also I've noticed that on firefox, the video is displayed as rotated but chrome manages to display the video correctly.

I have two questions:

- How can I get the metadata information of the videos `displaymatrix` rotation with the C API?
- How can I flip the video to be displayed correctly, preferably inside the C API?

Note that I want to change the data inside the buffer so the aspect ratio remains the same. So I want the bottom video to look like the top one.

Comment: Here is a link for the function: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/display.c You can clone the entire source of ffmpeg from the git repository. This will have the source to ffprobe so you can see how it uses the API functions

Comment: It really depends on how you are using the opengl library to handle the data given. Opengl is quite complicated when it comes to displaying things like this.

Comment: I am curious... does my answer return the correct rotation angle?

Answer (score 3):

The [following C source code](https://cpp.hotexamples.com/site/file?hash=0x05a4995b978621f208fab8032d172786e9c207e97b0ac341a640b3bd9a980f6b&fullName=ijkplayer-master/ijkmedia/ff_cmdutils.c&project=15034189148/ijkplayer) found by [hotexamples.com](https://cpp.hotexamples.com/site/file?hash=0x05a4995b978621f208fab8032d172786e9c207e97b0ac341a640b3bd9a980f6b&fullName=ijkplayer-master/ijkmedia/ff_cmdutils.c&project=15034189148/ijkplayer) has a nice example for reading the rotation.

Here is a complete code sample (with some C++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/dict.h>
#include "libavutil/display.h"
#include "libavutil/eval.h"
}


//https://cpp.hotexamples.com/site/file?hash=0x05a4995b978621f208fab8032d172786e9c207e97b0ac341a640b3bd9a980f6b&fullName=ijkplayer-master/ijkmedia/ff_cmdutils.c&project=15034189148/ijkplayer
double get_rotation(AVStream *st)
{
    AVDictionaryEntry *rotate_tag = av_dict_get(st->metadata, "rotate", NULL, 0);
    uint8_t* displaymatrix = av_stream_get_side_data(st,
                                                     AV_PKT_DATA_DISPLAYMATRIX, NULL);
    double theta = 0;

    if (rotate_tag && (*rotate_tag->value) && strcmp(rotate_tag->value, "0"))
    {
        char *tail;
        theta = av_strtod(rotate_tag->value, &tail);
        if (*tail)
        {
            theta = 0;
        }
    }

    if (displaymatrix && !theta)
    {
        theta = -av_display_rotation_get((int32_t*)displaymatrix);
    }

    theta -= 360*floor(theta/360 + 0.9/360);

    //if (fabs(theta - 90*round(theta/90)) > 2)
    //    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_WARNING, "Odd rotation angle.\n"
    //           "If you want to help, upload a sample "
    //           "of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/incoming/ "
    //           "and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list. (ffmpeg-devel@ffmpeg.org)");

    return theta;
}


// helper function to check for FFmpeg errors
static void checkError(int error, const std::string& message) {
    if (error < 0) {
        //std::cerr << message << ": " << av_err2str(error) << std::endl;  //error C4576: a parenthesized type followed by an initializer list is a non-standard explicit type conversion syntax
        std::cerr << message << ": " << std::to_string(error) << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


int main ()
{
    std::string inputFileName = "phone_video.mp4";

    AVFormatContext* formatContext = nullptr;
    int error = avformat_open_input(&formatContext, inputFileName.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);
    checkError(error, "Error opening input file");

    error = avformat_find_stream_info(formatContext, nullptr);
    checkError(error, "Error avformat find stream info");

    // find the video stream
    AVStream* videoStream = nullptr;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < formatContext->nb_streams; i++) 
    {
        if ((formatContext->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) && !videoStream) 
        {
            videoStream = formatContext->streams[i];
        }
    }

    if (!videoStream) 
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: input file does not contain a video stream" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    double theta = get_rotation(videoStream);

    //Fix value of theta for getting the same result as FFprobe.
    theta = -theta;
    if (theta < -180)
    {
        theta += 360;
    }
    else if (theta >= 180.0)
    {
        theta -= 360;
    }

    printf("theta = %lf\n", theta);

    avformat_close_input(&formatContext);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Note:
I can't verify that the above code sample works with your phone video - there may be some other way for marking the rotation.

---

Flipping/Rotating the video using C API of FFmpeg may be more difficult than you may think.
I found a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719959/rotating-a-video-during-encoding-with-ffmpeg-and-libav-api-results-in-half-of-vi), but with no answer.
I recommend you to do some research and post a specific question about it.